# Flux Javadoc Images not visible in reader mode - Intellij ( visible only when hovering over method)

Tags: image, intellij-idea, flux

Images in java doc of reactor.core.publisher.Flux is very informative but is not visible in reader mode ( only on hover mode from calling class).

Visible in calling class (hovering over method):
[image]

Not visible when drilled down in Javadoc:
[image]

Using latest IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a known bug. See if the workaround https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256643/SVG-images-are-not-shown-in-rendered-docs#focus=Comments-27-5379180.0-0 helps